# Ajax post calling wrong url

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc

Good day.

I want to know why is my project calling the wrong url? The code is:

**SCRIPT**

```
 $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/Application/Franchise",
            data: JSON.stringify(sendInfo),
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function (result) {
                  $('#myModal3').modal('hide'); //hide the modal
            },
            error: function () {
                alert("Error while inserting data");
            }
        });
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
public class ApplicationController : Controller
{
public ActionResult Franchise()
{
 return View();
}
}
```

I even tried changing the url by 'Url.Action("Franchise", "Application")' but still the system kept on bringing me to `http://localhost:49267/Home/Franchise`.

I can't understand what is wrong here. Is there a bug in jquery ajax url post?

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE**

```
<button class="btn btn-success" type="button" id="btnCapture">Submit</button>

@section Scripts{
<script src="~/Scripts/webcam.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/webcam.js"></script>

<script language="JavaScript">
    Webcam.set({
        width: 320,
        height: 240,
        image_format: 'jpeg',
        jpeg_quality: 90
    });
    Webcam.attach( '#my_camera' );
</script>

<script language="JavaScript">
    function take_snapshot() {
        Webcam.snap( function(data_uri) {
            document.getElementById('results').innerHTML =
                '<img id="base64image" src="' + data_uri + '"/>';
        } );
    }
</script>
<script>
$(document).on("click", ".open-camera", function () {
            var myBookId = $(this).data('id');
            $(".modal-body #franid").val(myBookId);
        })
</script>

<script>
$(function(){
     $('#btnCapture').on('click', function(){
         var file = document.getElementById("base64image").src;
         var franid = $("#franid").val();

         var sendInfo = {
             Imagee: file,
             FranIDD: franid
         };

         $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/Application/Franchise",
            data: JSON.stringify(sendInfo),
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function (result) {
                  $('#myModal3').modal('hide'); //hide the modal
            },
            error: function () {
                alert("Error while inserting data");
            }
        });
     });
 });
</script>
}
```

This is all my code.

Comment: The code you have shown will not go to `../Home/Franchise` - if it is, then its due to code you have not shown. What is triggering that ajax call?

Comment: And why are you passing data to a method which does not have any parameters to bind the data?

Comment: @StephenMuecke I will just update my code sir

Comment: @StephenMuecke I have a modal wherein if the user clicks the button, it will popup including the ID. Now I wanted to submit the data from modal to controller method. I did it by using ajax post method but unfortunately this happens.

Comment: The code you have show will work fine. Is your script even being executed?

Comment: Looks like you just have get method in your controller. Try adding a method in the controller with HTTPPost attribute.

Comment: @StephenMuecke Yes sir. That is why I am really confused right now. Why is my code posting to Home not in Applications

Comment: @PNDev I have post method in my controller. I just forgot to include it in the solution above.

Comment: Its not due to the code you have shown. Do you have any route definitions that may be causing the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Ok. So I found my problem. It was in my controller.

In my controller I tried adding `return RedirectToAction("Franchise", "Home");` after the save command. As soon as I commented this, everything worked.

Thanks for the help again guys.

Answer (score -1):

Please use the browser to access directly, not from within the IDE directly access, from the localhost:49267 should be from the IDE access, and you will write URL as http://www.google.com try.

Comment: This has nothing at all to do with the question, and it does not even make sense.